# Is there an open source class somewhere for handling user comments?

Tags: php, open-source, class, comments

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a class that exists for handling user comments already. I can always write my own, but I figure I wouldn't re-invent the wheel if there is one out there.

Id like to be able to display a comment form, manipulate/validate/sanitize user input, and possibly more functions such as inserting into a database.

If anyone knows of any classes/packages that already implement this sort of thing, I'd love it if they could share.

Thank you,

Comment: Inserting into a DB is very specific, and would definitely be outside the scope of a (well-designed) general purpose comment library. Captcha, validation/sanitization, gravatar/Identicon (google them), would all be relevant to a general-purpose comment library though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from collaborating with a 3rd party ASP-style vendor (like [Pluck](http://pluck.com/)), I'm not sure you're going to find something like this.

I've seen components to support comments in the ORM (such as [Commentable Behavior Plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPropelActAsCommentableBehaviorPlugin) for Propel within symfony) but that doesn't give you anything in the way of forms, sanitization, display, user validation, etc.

And then there's the question of features: Do you want flaggable comments? Rich HTML?  Emoticons? URL Parsing? Nested comments? Moderation tools? Profanity filtering?

I suppose all of this depends heavily on what type of existing system you're adding this to, as well (can you leverage AJAX? MVC? Postbacks? etc) but really I think it's a fairly broad topic which is why you'll probably just want to roll your own.

Answer (score -1):

Another 3rd party option is www.kickapp.com which seems to be pretty decent.